How to render svg image in Flutter
I am working on flutter app, where I am generating QR code for payment. When user click on Generate QR code button, it will call an API which return svg.
My problem is that when I receive this svg from API, I update state. In my code, I have condition that if this state is null, display button, else display svg. However, I click on button, state is updated but my UI is not updated. I need to click on for example text input to see this image. How can I fix this problem, so that after button click it will update UI without me needing to click somewhere?
I also tried to add spinner until API request is completed, but again, state was updated (I printed everything), but spinner was spinning infinitely.
Here is how I declare svg image variable
String? paymentQrCode;

Here is my function, which is getting svg from API and updating state.
handleQrCodePaymentMethod() async {
    try {
      final authService = AuthenticationService();
      final dioClient = DioClient(authService);
      ApiClient apiClient =
          ApiClient(baseUrl: Env.apiUrl, dioClient: dioClient);

      String endpoint = 'funds/generate-payment';

      Map<String, String> data = {
        'paymentType': 'qrCode',
        'iban': _iban,
        'bic': _swift,
        'bank': _bankName,
        'paymentIdentification': widget.accountId,
        'amount': _priceController.text,
        'currency': _selectedFundsCurrency.toString(),
      };

      var response = await apiClient.performPostRequest(endpoint, data);

      if (response['response'] == 'OK') {
        setState(() {
          paymentQrCode = response['qrCode'];
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Catch error: $e');
    }
  }

And here is my how I call my dialog and also dialog it self.
PopupMenuButton<String>(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert,
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(235, 235, 245, 0.6)),
                            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0)),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            onSelected: (String value) {
                              if (value == 'settings') {
                                _settings(context, widget.name,
                                    widget.investmentTarget);
                              } else if (value == 'addFunds') {
                                _addFunds(context);
                              } else if (value == 'accountStatement') {
                                _accountStatement(context);
                              } else if (value == 'taxAccountStatement') {
                                _taxAccountStatement(context);
                              }
                            },

AddFunds dialog:
Future<bool> _addFunds(BuildContext context) {
    bool isDepositInfoVisible = false;

    return showDialog<bool>(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setStateDialog) {
            return AlertDialog(
              contentPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 20),
              insetPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 20),
              title: Row(
                children: [

....
paymentQrCode == null
                                                      ? ElevatedButton(
                                                          onPressed: () =>
                                                              handleQrCodePaymentMethod(),
                                                          style: ElevatedButton
                                                              .styleFrom(
                                                            minimumSize:
                                                                const Size(
                                                                    200, 50),
                                                            padding:
                                                                const EdgeInsets
                                                                    .symmetric(
                                                                    vertical:
                                                                        14.0,
                                                                    horizontal:
                                                                        20.0),
                                                            backgroundColor:
                                                                const Color
                                                                    .fromRGBO(
                                                                    0,
                                                                    122,
                                                                    255,
                                                                    1),
                                                            foregroundColor:
                                                                Colors.white,
                                                          ),
                                                          child: Text(
                                                            AppLocalizations.of(
                                                                    context)!
                                                                .detailsGenerateButton,
                                                          ),
                                                        )
                                                      : Padding(
                                                          padding:
                                                              const EdgeInsets
                                                                  .only(
                                                                  bottom: 65.0),
                                                          child:
                                                              SvgPicture.string(
                                                            paymentQrCode
                                                                .toString(),
                                                            key: ValueKey<
                                                                    String>(
                                                                paymentQrCode
                                                                    .toString()),
                                                            height: 330,
                                                            width: 330,
                                                          ),
                                                        )            

   

So as you can see, there is part where I check if paymentQrCode is null, then I display button, else I display svg image itself.
Thanks for any advices!

I managed to get it working.
In my addFunds dialog I am declaring 'StateSetter setStateDialog'.
 Future<bool> _addFunds(BuildContext context) {
    bool isDepositInfoVisible = false;

    return showDialog<bool>(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setStateDialog) {
            return AlertDialog(

I tried to pass it as a parameter to function, where I am saving state.
onPressed: () => handleQrCodePaymentMethod(setStateDialog),

And then, instead of setState, I called this parameter setStateDialog
if (response['response'] == 'OK') {
        setStateDialog(() {
          paymentQrCode = response['qrCode'];
        });
      }

And now, my QR code displays after I click on generate :)

Use flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1. It provides an option to fetch SVG images from the internet via a URL and display a placeholder until the image loads.
Use below code to show network svg using flutter_svg package
SvgPicture.network(
  'https://site-that-takes-a-while.com/image.svg',
  semanticsLabel: 'A shark?!',
  placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
)


Thank you for answer, but still same result. I clicked on generate button, nothing happends. Then I click on anything else and spinner showed up and spin forever.

Please update the code first

can you try with a sample svg url to check if it loads properly and can you also try to print the url from api request just after response.body

I updated that code, I also tried sample svg url but result is same. I can see that svg image, but I need to click somewhere else to be able to see it.
Response:
<path stroke="#000000" d="M1 1.5h7m2 0h3m1 0h2m3 0h7m1 0h2m1 0h2m1 0h1m1 0h7M1 2.5h1m5 0h1m2 0h1m1 0h1m2 0h2m1 0h1m5 0h2m5 0h3m1 0h1m5 0h1M1 3.5h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m3 0h3m1 0h1m2 0h1m1 0h1m1 ....
Can't place whole response in comment

you need to edit your question and add it. Your other code is incomplete, from the behavior you said, there is some prblm with click events, may be the svg is not called first time when clicked but on second time. It's hard to undertand without full code. Can you atleast add the whole widget where you call the api fn.
